# Migrating ASP.NET Web Application to Mac Rider

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, macos, rider

I have a project on VS 2019 Windows machine that is fairly small but containing Web Forms. I have taken the whole project folder zipped it and loaded it in directly to JetBrains rider on the Mac. Here is what it looks like currently.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMToc.png) Errors on solution
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYTMa.png) What the error says on every web form page

It appears that the System.Web.UI is not accepted on the Mac.

I have looked all over and the forums are telling me to download a package that proceeds it. This does not exist either. How do you replace the System.Web.UI?

Comment: The only feasible way to go cross platform, is to migrate to ASP.NET Core/Blazor, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/.

Comment: So there is no way to really use another IDE after you start a web form project in visual studio? I mean if this is the case, I would never use that feature if it weren't for a school assignment. Pretty disappointed that it is not something that is standard across platforms.

Comment: School assignments are there to get you started on the platform, but they might be the actual direction the industry is moving towards. ASP.NET Web Forms is too old https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/choose-aspnet-framework?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @LexLi I realized this after hours of research and figured out that most people are using MVC that being the reason why JetBrains is creating the web application with them. So, I accepted the fact that you would need to create a master page and a separate _layout.cshtml... web forms seem so out of date! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

WebForms are out of date and cross-platform of the web form is not impossible, but you will need to take into consideration everything that is used on the master page. It is not only a problem with MAC but any other IDE other than Visual Studio. You are better off migrating to the MVC style, it may take time but it appears to be the industry standard. WebForms are supported in Rider, however, you must manually create all the pages that belong with it like the master, and ensuring the routing is the same. Also, it seems to be severely difficult to connect an MVC application with WebForms. You would have to create the same exact style with _layout.cshtml and Site.master page. Seems like an outdated process that works if you want to just make forms.